# Non-preemptive? Non-pre-emptive? Emptive?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

We can describe something as pre-emptive, no issue there.

If something isn't such, how can we write that? Word gives me red squiggles on 'Non-preemptive', but this looks silly with a double hyphenation.

Which leads me to wonder why 'pre-emptive' is hyphenated anyway? 'Emptive' isn't a word, and other 'pre' prefixes aren't hyphenated (e.g. prefix, predecessor).

Comment: Is preemptive actually hyphenated? I've always written it as one word.

Comment: @pavja2 http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-emptive

Comment: Yeah but https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preemptive%2C+pre-emptive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreemptive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpre%20-%20emptive%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Like [nonpreemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonpreemptive_multitasking)?

Comment: If it isn't preemptive, it's reactive

Comment: I'll never get over this site's love of ngrams. What you've shown is that, yes, it's used without 2-3x as much. Great, but they're both used, and every dictionary says it should be hyphenated.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch *Exactly* like that. But the term is written in all manner of styles, which is why I ask.

Comment: @Andy - tech terms will be tech terms. I should've clarified, but I thought it was enough to not ask for a word suggestion.

Comment: The full OED entry gives it an alternate form "Forms:  17– pre-emptive, 18 preëmptive." 

Either way, I'd love to see if there's an explanation for why the variation has flipped from favoring hyphen to not.

Comment: @pavja2 Yeah that is interesting - flipped 3x too - that peak around 1960.. weird.

Comment: @OllieFord For the computer science term I'd use *nonpreemptive multitasking*.

Comment: _emptor_ is a word for _buyer_, _emption_ is a word for _buying_. Neither in common use these days except for _caveat emptor_. _Pre-emptor_ (or preemptor) is someone who has struck a deal to buy something before it is offered to the general public. I imagine (which why this isn't an answer) is that _empt_ became the part of the word _preempt_ to mean 'prior action' not just buying stuff.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But why no hyphen after 'non'? Isn't 'non' always 'non-'?

Comment: Nonsense and I am aware of nonesuch rule!

Comment: I'll concede that you're correct for 'nonsense' (d'oh!) - but 'nonesuch' is not an example of that. *Not one such -> None such -> nonesuch*.

Comment: Ollie Ford, the spelling seems to be a US/UK difference. See the **Hyphens** section at the bottom of the page, at this link http://www.lukemastin.com/testing/spelling/cgi-bin/database.cgi?action=rules

Comment: OED agrees with @Frank, and adds that preempt is a back formation of preemption. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preemption

Comment: @Andy - Ironically, in computing, pre-emptive operating systems are more reactive than non-preemptive ones! :)

Comment: @GMB - Are you using your link to argue against the hyphen?   Or just confirming the etymology?    What do we make of this, at the same site:  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pre-emption  ?    It seems to all line up with Tristan's reference that tells us that the hyphenation is regional.

Comment: @GreenAsJade - Just confirming the etymology.I don't consider a hyphen necessary in preemptive anymore so than in preeminent.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibile ways to describe something that is not pre-emptive.

1) **Non-preemptive**.

This is used in computing.  In this context, the choice of hypenation appears arbitrary.   A simple google seach for nonpreemptive operating system shows that one hyphen is the most common choice.     "Non-preemptive operating systems are not a good choice in a situation where reaction time is important".

2) **Reactive** or **reactionary**.

This is used in a military context.   "They decided not to make a pre-emptive strike.  As a result, their strikes, when they finally responded to provocation, were reactionary, and all too late..."

Comment: +1, all good stuff. I would simply add that the _preventive/reactive_ dichotomy exists in other fields than the military example given, such as medicine and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't hypenate preemptive and Webster's and other lexicographers googled tended to agree (but see Cambridge and Oxford).

And, I thought pre-emptor was the best answer.

But your reference to "emptive" or "empt" led me to a thesis. Empt is listed in Webster's as Definition of empt ++ -ed/-ing/-s ++ now dialectal : empty.

Agreeing with another response, the opposite of preempt is react. To react is to respond to a causal act. To prempt is to respond without, or in advance of, a causal act -- a response to empty or nothing.

BTW, I got here after having used "post-emptive" facetiously to describe  conduct.